# train_test_split with multiple features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm currently trying to train a data set with a decision tree classifier but I couldn't get the train_test_split to work.

From the code below CS is the target output and EN SN JT FT PW YR LO LA are features input.

All variables that went through OHL are in sparse matrix format whereas the other are in array taken straight from the dataframe.

```
def OHL(x, column): #OneHotEncoder
    le = LabelEncoder()
    enc = OneHotEncoder()
    Labeled = le.fit_transform(x[column].astype(str))
    return enc.fit_transform(Labeled.reshape(-1,1))

###------------------------------------------------------------------------

df = pd.read_csv('h1b_kaggle.csv')
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0','WORKSITE'],1)

###------------------------------------------------------------------------

CS = OHL(df, 'CASE_STATUS')
EN = OHL(df, 'EMPLOYER_NAME')
SN = OHL(df, 'SOC_NAME')
JT = OHL(df, 'JOB_TITLE')
FT = OHL(df, 'FULL_TIME_POSITION')
PW = np.array(df['PREVAILING_WAGE'])
YR = OHL(df, 'YEAR')
LO = np.array(df['lon'])
LA = np.array(df['lat'])
```

Comment: Why do you have all these features in individual variables instead of a single array? That would be easier to handle and use in scikit-learn

Comment: I tried to put them in array but it has MemoryError.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), you can see it takes an `*arrays` argument. To split the first three of your arguments, therefore, you could use

```
CS_tr, CS_te, EN_tr, EN_te, SN_tr, SN_te = train_test_split(CS, EN, SN)
```

(of course, you can pass more arrays than that).

Note that current versions of `sklearn` return sparse arrays when given sparse arrays.

Comment: But after i do this and i want to use tree.DecisionTreeClassifier dont I have to group this into one variable? the fit function takes only 1 feature and 1 target.